# Adding Pace.js loader to angular.js modal containing videos

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have angular ui bootstrap modal which has videos, I have posted same question week ago here is the link of that question [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061341/adding-ajax-loader-in-angular-ui-bootstrap-modal) ,
 but did'nt got any response, anyhow i found pace.js [adds loader automatically](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/). Now can anybody tell me how do i add pace.js loader for modal containing videos. I have added this loader for my pages in  app but not getting how to use with modal. Thanks

This is the snap where two pace loaders collaborating
[image]

Comment: Look at the API you have Pace.start and Pace.stop call start when you open modal and stop on iframe onload (but that's for loading video player not the video, but when you include youtube video you will get YT loadindicator).

Comment: Yeah sir you are right..and thanks for the response. I have included two pace loaders on same page. so whenever am loading that pace loader other one is also loaded, and there is nothing to stop specific loader in pace.js. I will paste you the snap if possible in this u take a look. both loaders are mixing.

Comment: @jcubic i have added the snap, this is how two loaders are collaborating. If you have any link to add ajax loader to ng-BS-modal then please provide me sir.

Comment: From API it look like it's just one global loader, you'll will need to fork and modify the library (or use differnt one) to have a way to create instance, like `var p1 = new peace();`, but I don't think you'll get progress bar because peace don't handle iframes. You can ask this question on github https://github.com/HubSpot/pace/issues

Comment: The best way is to create your own loader (you can get style from peace), but you will not have % progress because you can only have one event that iframe have been loaded, at the end.

Comment: Well, i will see, Thanks a lot sir. can i have your mail id in case if i want to contact you, if u dnt mind. bye.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56809/discussion-between-sudarshan-and-jcubic).