# Angular js checkbox to count checked checkbox's using $watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to check any 3 checkbox's at any point of time from the list, when the length of the selected checkbox's is equal to 3 then I want to disable all the remaining checkbox's(unchecked checkbox's). But checkboxes which are selected should be in enabled state. I want to achieve this using $watch if possible.( At any point of time user can select only 3 checkboxs;)
Here is my html code-

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="std in students">
        {{std.name}}<input type="checkbox" ng-model="std.selected" ng-checked="" ng-disabled=""/>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my app.js

```
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.students=[
  {selected:"f", name:"peter"},
  {selected:"f", name:"santa"},
  {selected:"f",name:"rita"},
  {selected:"f", name:"shona"},
  {selected:"f", name:"mickey"},
  {selected:"f",name:"nicky"}
]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller code:

```
    $scope.students=[
      {selected:false, name:"peter"},
      {selected:false, name:"santa"},
      {selected:false, name:"rita"},
      {selected:false, name:"shona"},
      {selected:false, name:"mickey"},
      {selected:false, name:"nicky"}
    ];
    $scope.disabledCheckboxes = false;
    $scope.checked = function() {
        $scope.disabledCheckboxes = $scope.students.filter(function(ch) {
            return ch.selected;
        }).length > 3;
    };
```

and html:

```
    <div ng-repeat="std in students">
       {{std.name}}
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="std.selected" ng-change="checked()"
              ng-disabled="disabledCheckboxes && !std.selected"/>
    </div>
```

with `&& !std.selected` you will be able to uncheck selected checkboxes.

Comment: You can achieve the same using a watch. But I'd say this is clearer.

Comment: I need this using watch, because my selected_students list is different from students. In my selected_students list at any time there will be 3 students selected where as in students std.selected is  default false in database. I cant use !std.selected because that fetching from database which is always false, I pushed 3 students from students in selected_students in which selected value changes.

Comment: I will explain whats happening in my code. when user checks one student from students list, I pushed that student into selected_students list which is temp array. Now selected field in selected_students keeps changing but in students array i stored selected as false by default. so cant use !std.selected because it is always false. How can i use selected_students list? if i use that list then it checks only 3 records as its length is 3 at any time. please help @jcubic

Comment: @Sudarshan it's even simpler, you don't need to filter original list with selected true to count selected users but just use  `$scope.checked = function() { $scope.disabledCheckboxes = $scope.selected_students.length > 3; }`.

Comment: Thanks @jcubic I just removed default value from my database which was always false, and created temp model with std.selected. I was not getting to disable checks using ng. inside $watch i checked if std.selected==t && len===3 then disable all remaining checks. thnks.

Comment: @jcubic I have one more ? with respect to angular.bootstrap modal please have a look here... I posted two times with my code nobody solved..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199097/adding-pace-js-loader-to-angular-js-modal-containing-videos